# В чём ошибка в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
let userName = prompt("Кто там?");

if (userName == "Админ") {
    let pass = prompt("Пароль?");

    if (pass == "Я главный") {
    alert("Здравствуйте");
}   else if (pass === '' || pass === null); {
    alert("Отменено");
}   else {
    alert("Неверный пароль");
}

}   else if (userName === '' || userName === null) {
    alert("Отменено");
}   else {
    alert("Я Вас не знаю");
}
```

Comment: Проверьте соответствие открывающих и закрывающих фигурных скобок

Comment: точка с запятой лишняя на 8-ой строке после скобок в else if